# jQuery: input reports empty when not

Tags: jquery, events

I am pulling my hair out about this one, hope someone can help. I have content and Javascript that is dynamically inserted into a page, and it looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input#employee_id2").on("keyup", function(){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
            $("button.signinbutton").on("click", function(e){
                var empn = $("input#employee_id2").val();
                var empc = $("input#cell2").val();
                alert(empn);
                alert(empc);
                e.preventDefault();
                // .. Some more stuff that is irrelevant.
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The first selector with the keyup is just there to show that there is actually a value in the input, and this works 100%, however, when I set the variables in the second part of this script, they alert empty values. How is this possible?

EDIT: In my code it does not work, and in my fiddle it does: http://jsfiddle.net/bliksempie/Qs8BG/1/

Full source of the generated page at the time this problem occurs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>X</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="x,y,z" />
        <meta name="description" content="X" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/js/validationengine/validationEngine.jquery.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/js/sudoslider/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/js/sudoslider/css/lib/animate.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/x/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-ie7.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/jquery.migrate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/validationengine/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/validationengine/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="top"></a>
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="content" class="row-fluid">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function(){           
                                    var sudoSlider = $("#home-sudoslider").sudoSlider({
                                        responsive: true,
                                        prevNext: false,
                                        numeric:false,
                                        continuous:true,
                                        customLink:'a.customlink'
                                    });             
                                });
                            </script>    
                            <div class="home-sudo-container pad-top-20" style="position:relative;">
                                <div id="home-sudoslider">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/x/assets/uploads/sudoslider/slide-1.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <img src="http://localhost/x/assets/uploads/sudoslider/slide-2.jpg" alt="" />               
                                    <img src="http://localhost/x/assets/uploads/sudoslider/slide-3.jpg" alt="" />                       
                                    <div class="signin-div">
                                        <div class="row-fluid footer">
                                            <div class="span6 offset6" style="margin-top: 25%">
                                                <form action="http://localhost/x/signin-step-2" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="signin-form-2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    Employee ID: <input type="text" name="employee_id2" value="" id="employee_id2" class="validate[required] input-xlarge"  /><br />    
                                                    Cellular number: <input type="text" name="cell2" value="" id="cell2" class="validate[required,min[10]|max[10]] input-xlarge"  /><br />        
                                                    <button name="submitbutton" type="button" id="submitbutton" class="signinbutton btn btn-success" value="" >Sign me in</button>
                                                </form>
                                                <p id="signin-result"></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                                $("input#employee_id2").on("keyup", function(e){
                                                    alert($(this).val());
                                                });
                                                $("button.signinbutton").on("click", function(e){
                                                    var empn = $("input#employee_id2").val();
                                                    var empc = $("input#cell2").val();
                                                    alert(empn);
                                                    alert(empc);
                                                    if (empc == "")
                                                    {
                                                        empc = "";
                                                    }
                                                    var url = encodeURI("http://localhost/x/signin/signin_submit/" + empn + "/" + empc);
                                                    $.ajax(url, {
                                                        success: function(response){
                                                            alert(response);
                                                            if (response == -1)
                                                            {
                                                                $("p#signin-result").html("<strong>Oops!</strong> You have to provide your employee number in order to sign in.");
                                                                $("p#signin-result").show("slow");
                                                            }
                                                            else if (response == 0)
                                                            {
                                                                $("p#signin-result").html("<strong>Oops!</strong> Unfortunately, your employee ID was not found on the system. Please contact X Y at <a href=\"mailto:x@x.y\">x@x.y</a>.");
                                                                $("p#signin-result").show("slow");
                                                            }
                                                            else if (response == 1)
                                                            {
                                                                window.location = "http://localhost/x/signin/check_and_redirect";
                                                            }
                                                         }
                                                    });
                                                    e.preventDefault();
                                                });
                                           });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a rel="next" class="customlink home-next-button"></a>          
                                <a rel="last" class="customlink home-final-button"></a>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/less/less-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/sudoslider/js/jquery.sudoSlider.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/x/assets/js/sudoslider/js/lib/jquery.touchSwipe.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: When the code was inside a slider (Sudo Slider) it bombs out. When I move it out of the containing div of the slider, it works :-) I have opted to remove the slider instead, so the problem was not solved, but I got around it at least...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: We'll need to see the markup/code adding the elements dynamically as well. Fundamentally, `empn` and `empc` should be the values as of the click.

Comment: It does work, so there's something we're not seeing here that's causing the problem... http://jsfiddle.net/9UBwA/

Comment: Side note: `id` values are required to be unique, so there's never any need to qualify them with a tag name except in the very unusual use-case where sometimes the `id` will be applied to one kind of element, other times to a different kind (but never at the *same* time), and you only want to get the element if it's of that type.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bliksempie/Qs8BG/1/ - yes, it works in my fiddle as well. I just don't get it. The inputs are in my fiddle, and it works, but in my code it does not. The code that adds the code dynamically is quite elaborate, so not sure how to provide that to you. As for the qualified IDs, I did that simply to be more specific, as I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh: When improving a question, use the "edit" link to add information, not comments. If your fiddle works (and it works even if I change it so jsFiddle doesn't wrap your code in another DOM ready wrapper - http://jsfiddle.net/Qs8BG/2/), then there isn't enough information in your question for us to be able to help you. You have to narrow the problem down. I can **guess** that the input elements don't exist with those `id` values on your real page, or aren't `input` elements, or something is preventing their actually having values. But those are guesses.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. I improved the question, and added the full generated source. Hope this helps to get help?

Comment: @KobusMyburgh: Since that doesn't replicate the problem, I'm afraid we can't help you. Your best bet is to walk through the code in the debugger. Check that you're finding the elements, then look at the raw element's value, etc., etc. Good luck with it.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce your problem even with a [JSBin test](http://jsbin.com/eXiZOBi/1/) based on the source that you provided. Try to provide a minimal example that is reproducible or step through you code as @T.J.Crowder suggested.

Comment: Thanks, all... I am still stumped. I have tried everything. Perhaps a whole rewrite is the way to go...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I found why the problem is there, but not sure how to fix it. See EDIT2, if you're interested in looking again...

Comment: Edit your question to include what you discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See EDIT2 near the bottom of my question. Removed code from within the slider. Somehow the slider "broke" it. Now I am slider-less, but at least the site works :-)